# When defining a new variable, how to decide its type according to the string value of a constant (or other variable)?

Tags: rust, types, typing, string-constant

I want to be able to decide the type of a new variable by the name of a previous variable, for example:

```
//the text of this variable must determine the type of the second variable
const TYPE_NAME: &str = "u16";
fn main() {
    //if this worked, this second_variable must be of type u16, which is the string text indicated in type_name
    let second_variable: {TYPE_NAME} = 777;
    println!("TYPE_NAME: {}, second_variable: {}", TYPE_NAME, second_variable);
}
```

However this code is incorrect, and I get this error:

```
error[E0573]: expected type, found constant `TYPE_NAME`
 --> test.rs:5:23
  |
5 |     let second_variable: TYPE_NAME = 777;
  |                          ^^^^^^^^^ not a type

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0573`.
```

How can I do this? Is there some other way to do it besides a match loop?

The detail is that this must be used in multiple parts of the code, and will ideally be defined with a constant, so, for example, I can in one line change the maximum value of my numeric variables from u16 to u32 or turn them into floats f64, or something like that.

Comment: The reason we remove the "In Rust" in the title is because it is redundant and makes the read flow harder. We already see the [rust] tag in the questions list, and the title also includes "rust - ...". However, @JohnKugelman, please try to avoid edit wars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot declare a type from a string, but what you want is a [type alias](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#creating-type-synonyms-with-type-aliases):

```rust
type Type = u16;

let second_variable: Type = 777;
```